# Can we pass more than one props from a stateless component and get it as single arguments in another stateless component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to pass more than one props to a functional component and getting in the component as single argument props but getting error in InputBox component at placeholder as item is undefined

```
export default ({change, state}) => (
  <div style={styles.container}>
    <h3 style={{margin: 0, marginBottom: 15}}>InputData</h3>
    {items.map((item) => (
      <div style={styles.lineContainer}>
        {(() => {
          switch(item.name) {
            case "name1": return <InputBox handleChange ={change} state ={state} item={item}/>
            case "name2": return <SelectBox handleChange ={change} state ={state} item={item}/>;
            case "name3": return <SelectBox handleChange ={change} state ={state} item={item}/>;
            default: return <InputBox/>
          }
        })()}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);


const InputBox = props => 
     <input
        type="text"
        placeholder={props.item.place}
        name={props.item.name}
        value={props.state[props.item.name]}
        onChange={props.change}
        required
        style={{height: 20}}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can make out, this is happening because for default case in switch you are returning `<InputBox/>` without any props but inside your `InputBox` component you are trying to refer to a prop using props.item.place. Hence this error.

Either make sure that switch returns appropriate value for default case or configure component to adjust to props.

Answer (score 3):

There are more than one problems with your code.

1. in your first component, where the line is `items.map((item)=>....`, `items` is not defined anywhere.
   Assumption: maybe you had to destructure it from state or get another prop.
2. Your component `InputBox` is expecting some props, i.e., in `const InputBox = props =>...`.
   And these props are not being passed from `default: return <InputBox/>`, just like you did in `case "name1"`.

P.S, you can define default props if you don't have any intentions of sending props to `<InputBox />`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `items` array in your default export. I think you forgot to `destruct` it from your `state`.

Use `state.items.map(...)` instead of `items.map(...)` in your default export.